# Reformat text file spacing (strip tabs from imported text)

Tags: r

I have a text file that has sentences in this format:

```
Blah blah blah
blah blah blah.
Another random sentence
that sentence continued.
```

I was wondering if there was a way to reformat the text so there is no tab, so basically:

```
Blah blah blah blah blah blah.
Another random sentence that sentence continued.
```

Or:

```
Blah blah blah blah blah blah. Another random sentence that sentence continued.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options. It would be more clear what issue you're facing if you created the text file within your question or `dput()` what you get after reading in the text file.

```
fileConn <- file("delete_me.txt")

writeLines(c("Blah blah blah",
             "blah blah blah.",
             "Another random sentence",
             "that sentence continued."), fileConn)

close(fileConn)

text <- read.delim("delete_me.txt",
                    header=F)


text
```

> ```
>                         V1
> 1           Blah blah blah
> 2          blah blah blah.
> 3  Another random sentence
> 4 that sentence continued.
> ```

```
paste(text$V1, collapse = " ")
```

> ```
> [1] "Blah blah blah blah blah blah. Another random sentence that sentence continued."
> ```

Please let me know if you have questions.

```
text="Blah blah blah
blah blah blah.
Another random sentence
that sentence continued."

gsub("\n", " ", text)
```

> ```
> "Blah blah blah blah blah blah. Another random sentence that sentence continued."
> ```

```
strsplit(gsub("\n", "", text), ".",fixed=T)
```

> ```
> "Blah blah blahblah blah blah"                   
> "Another random sentencethat sentence continued"
> ```